# What's the type of the input parameter of user-defined function to accept nested JSON structs with arrays?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following nested JSON object (`cellsDF`) describing polygons (lots of them hence using Scala and Spark):

```
root
 |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Cell: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SignalStyrka: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

An example line is

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SignalStyrka": -82, "Cell": " 112" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 1292600.0, 6246350.0 ], [ 1292600.0, 6246400.0 ], [ 1292550.0, 6246400.0 ], [ 1292550.0, 6246350.0 ], [ 1292600.0, 6246350.0 ] ] ] } }
```

I'd like to find those polygons that include a given point. I've written UDFs in scala for finding these, but it seems Spark does not like the way I want to run UDFs on this nested JSON. Note that the inPolygon UDF is not written yet, just wanted to test if the whole concept works with UDFs. candidateCells are defined beforehand and that part of the code is working. 
I've tried a number of suggestions from SO (explode for example) without success. I managed to get it working with python, but not happy with the performance. Any support would be appreciated.

```
val cellsDF = spark.read.json("s3n://coverage-vectors/20170509/*.json.gz")
cellsDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [geometry: struct<coordinates: array<array<array<string>>>, type: string>, properties: struct<Cell: string, SignalStyrka: bigint> ... 1 more field]

def isCandidate(cell: String): Boolean = {
    candidateCells contains cell
}

def inPolygon(coordinates: Array[Array[Array[String]]]): Boolean = {
    coordinates.isEmpty

}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val udfCandidate = udf(isCandidate _)
val udfInPolygon = udf(inPolygon _)

cellsDF.filter(udfCandidate($"properties.Cell")).filter(udfInPolygon($"geometry.coordinates")).count()

isCandidate: (cell: String)Boolean
inPolygon: (coordinates: Array[Array[Array[String]]])Boolean
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
udfCandidate: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(StringType)))
udfInPolygon: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType,true),true),true))))
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 69.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 69.0 (TID 179, ip-172-31-12-172.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<array<array<string>>>) => boolean)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [[[Ljava.lang.String;
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:36)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Try changing `Array[Array[Array[String]]]` to `Array[Array[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]]`

Comment: YES! Tx a lot! All `Arrays` need to be changed to `collection.mutable.WrappedArray`.

Comment: great to hear that  it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of `inPolygon` to accept `Seq[Seq[Seq[String]]]` and you're done.

```
scala> in.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

val myUDF = udf { coordinates: Seq[Seq[Seq[String]]] => 1 }
scala> in.select(myUDF($"coordinates")).show
+----------------+
|UDF(coordinates)|
+----------------+
|               1|
+----------------+
```

---

You can see the conversion using [ArrayConverter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystTypeConverters.scala#L154-L174) and obviously in the very low-level [CatalystTypeConverters.getConverterForType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystTypeConverters.scala#L56).